# a problem at importing offline devices in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

when i import an offline device of genymotion in the virtualbox it starts to import but after one Minute it shows me an error

Failed to import appliance C:/Users/home/AppData/Local/Genymobile/Genymotion/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_6.0_181206_021806.ova.

Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\home\VirtualBox VMs\genymotion_vbox86p_6.0_181206_021806\android_system_disk.vmdk'.

VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in 'C:\Users\home\VirtualBox VMs\genymotion_vbox86p_6.0_181206_021806\android_system_disk.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: ApplianceWrap
Interface: IAppliance {8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e}

Please help me

thank

Comment: Maybe you don't have enough disk space left?

Comment: You are right.l'll try it